# disabling a javascript script when loaded on a smart phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, smartphone

I am using the following HTML fragment to load a different stylesheet for smartphones:

```
media="only screen and (min-device-width: 4801x)"
media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
```

I would like to disable a certain javascript script for smartphone users as well. Is that possible? I don't think i can do:

`<script media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" t ype="text/javascript" src=""/>`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect the screen resolution in javascript and then change script execution based on the resolution. But the javascript file will still be loaded. To detect the screen size:

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm

Comment: No the file will not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

If the phone's browser does not support javascript then it won't matter. If it does, you can use javascript to determine whether it supports what you are looking for and, if not, divert the execution to either a simpler path or to exit altogether.