# tell html doc not to load js if mobile device

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I'm cheekily seeking a line or two of code on the fly here:

Could someone be kind enough to provide code to place in the head section of html doc that says if mobile then do not load JS?

This is being used in conjunction with the following CSS media query:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="m/styles_mobile.css" />
```

So I'm looking for a piece of code that is based on the same rule: media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"

Would be very grateful

Comment: you might wanna refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053695/disabling-a-javascript-script-when-loaded-on-a-smart-phone

Comment: thanks I followed the link. Disappointing to see that it says the script will load anyway, I was hoping to improve/help load times/data use on mobile by not running script on mobile.

So reading whats there if I was to write: <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
if ((screen.width>=480) " 

what would I write next to say if true do not load or use script?

Comment: you can check the `screen size` through `js` and then only load `scripts` that are needed `dynamically`..I'll write you a quick one!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given: "if mobile then **do not load JS**", and presuming "mobile" is defined by screens with a width of 480 pixels or less, then something like the following should work:

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

That will add the script element only if the screen is greater than 480 pixels wide.

The CSS rule in the OP is:

```
<... media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" ...>
```

which will target screens of 480 pixels or less, which is contrary to to the first statement. Therefore change `>` to `<=` if the script should run on small screens and not run on larger ones.

Comment: The sign is flipped. It should be `<`. And also, it is not a good idea to use `document.write`.

Comment: The OP doesn't want the script to run if the device has a small screen, the sign seems right to me (though not what was used in the CSS rule).

Comment: I am not sure, but he did say `So I'm looking for a piece of code that is based on the same rule: media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"`.

Comment: `(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) ` should be used.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure how the previous answers would go with retina displays. I would do something like:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
```

snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Comment: I guess this is a better solution because there are already a lot Full HD mobile devices out there.

Comment: User-agent tests are the worst possible way to check for something. Use `window.devicePixelRatio` to check for high-density displays.

Comment: @Ry actually your method will fail in many cases, such as a retina macbook. ( just wanting to update the knowledge on this old thread )

Comment: @StevenStark: Eh? `devicePixelRatio` should be 2 on a Retina MacBook. (I am typing this from a Retina MacBook and just checked.)

Comment: @Ry This is pretty old, but devicePixelRatio won't nab older ios (pre retina) nor blackberry. Kind of outlier cases but nonetheless, my way is way better than your way.

Comment: @Dave: That’s the point – distinguishing pre-Retina from Retina and so on. It’s irrelevant anyway, though, because the other answers work fine on Retina displays already. (They measure CSS pixels, not physical ones.)

Answer (score 9):

Now it's possible to use `window.matchMedia`

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this.

1. Test the screen width and height to see if it is a mobile device.
2. Load in scripts using JavaScript.

What you can do is this:

```
var scripts = ["foo.js",       //Put all your scripts here.
               "bar.js"];

if(screen.width <= 480){
    for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
              //-with jQuery (one line!)-
        $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scripts[i]+'"><\/script>');
                 //-or jQuery free-
        var scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
        scriptEle.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        scriptEle.setAttribute("src",scripts[i]);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendElement(scriptEle);
    }
}
```

Notice it is `screen.width <= 480`.

Comment: Screen width and height don't tell you it's a mobile, only that it has a small screen. And shouldn't that be `>= 480` or just `> 479` or whatever.

Comment: @RobG, And that probably tells you it is a mobile device.

Comment: An iPad is mobile, what size is its screen? I have an internet phone sitting on my desk, it's small but doesn't move far.

Comment: Look, `media="only screen and` **`(max-device-width: 480px)"`**

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be to add it around whole the actual mobile script inside the "foo.js" file. The DOM will have trouble loading the  tag if you suddenly append it.

```
if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
 // Whole your script here
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
```