# Conditionally load Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I know there were similar questions, but I didn't find an answer. Is there an elegant way to conditionally load jquery library only `if screen > 481px` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508669/tell-html-doc-not-to-load-js-if-mobile-device

Comment: Write an `if` statement in JavaScript and use one of the techniques described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/218196 to load the file.

Comment: You can do it using JavaScript, but that may or may not defeat the point.

Comment: Yeah...@FelixKling spotted it.

Comment: As I already stated, I know there are similar topics here, but I didn't find an elegant and working answer.