# Dissable javascript in media query

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I use some JavaScript in my menu when user scroll my webpage. Here is [example](http://stefanvblog.com/category/news/)

All works fine but i want to dissable that effect in media query. Can i disasbel JavaScript in media query ..

```
@media only screen
 (max-device-width : 360px) {
//dissable JavaScript
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can i disasbel JavaScript in media query ..

No, you can't, neither with CSS Media rule nor with any other programming mechanism. JavaScript activation is a matter of the user preferences in the web-browser.

But you can always use workarounds like this one: [how to disable javascript for responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13235065/952310)

**Update:**

You can easily test the current CSS media type using jQuery and accordingly to activate your JS code:

```
var media = $('link[href$="yourStyleFile.css"]').attr('media');
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant disable JavaScript, but you can detect the resolution and not write the JavaScript.

[this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053695/disabling-a-javascript-script-when-loaded-on-a-smart-phone)